# Split user input string into a list with every character

Tags: python, micropython, text-segmentation, bbc-microbit

I'm trying to write a program for the micro:bit which displays text as morse code. I've looked at multiple websites and Stack Overflow posts for a way to split a string into characters.

E.g. 
`string = "hello"`
to 
`chars = ["h","e","l","l","o"]`

I tried creating a function called `array`, to do this, but this didn't work.

I then tried this:

```
def getMessage():
    file = open("file.txt", "r")
    data = file.readlines() 
    file.close()
    words = []
    for line in data:
        for word in line:
            words.append(word)
    return words
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `list("hello") == ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']`.

Comment: How would that work?

Comment: try list('hello') in an ipython console..

Comment: It works in normal IDLE as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use builtin list() function:

```
>>> list("A string") 
['A', ' ', 's', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g']
```

In your case, you can call list(getMessage()) to convert the contents of the file to chars.

Comment: `list` takes an arbitrary iterable value, and creates a list with each element of the iterable as separate list item. As an iterable, a `str` is considered to be made up of a sequence of one-character strings.

Answer (score -2):

You can try something like this:

word="hello"

result = [] 
result[:0] = word

print(result)

Now result will be ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']